# jQuery ajax call wont work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this:

```
$('.photoSaved').click(function () {
  var savedPhoto = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
    url: "status.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { mode: 'use', name: savedPhoto },
    success: function(){
      $.fancybox.close();
      $('#status_upContent').hide();
      $("#image").append($(document.createElement("img")).attr({src: "images/users/status/"+savedPhoto})).show();
    }
  });
});
```

with:

```
if($_POST['mode'] && $_POST['mode'] == 'use'){
  $_SESSION['status_attachedImage'] = $_POST['name'];
  echo 'ok';
}
```

I can see it make the request, but it doesnt give me the response "ok" and the success: doesnt execute

Comment: Try adding the `error` and `complete` handlers to see if there is an error. Also you can use `$('img').attr({src: "images/users/status/"+savedPhoto})`

Comment: You've told us what it doesn't do, but you haven't told us what it does do!

Comment: @DavidDorward I can see it makes the request in firebug

Comment: I hope your PHP is simplified and that in reality you do (or will) not store unfiltered POST data in your $_SESSION

Comment: So it makes the request. What response does it get? Firebug will show that.

Comment: @regilero I have not come that far to ask about how to filter the post data..

Comment: @DavidDorward the response is empty, thats the fun part. It should response "ok", but no response. I tried to make a quick html form and execute it to the same page file, same values and same method(post) and it works just fine..

Answer (score 2):

try adding the "error" callback. This will show you what is going wrong.

error(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)

> A function to be called if the request fails. The function is passed three arguments: The XMLHttpRequest object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "notmodified" and "parsererror". This is an Ajax Event.This handler is not called for JSONP requests, because they do not use an XMLHttpRequest.

So add in this line, similar to your `success` callback:

```
error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.error(errorThrown);
}
```

Comment: I added    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
   alert(textStatus);
   } And i just got "error" in the alert, when i alert errorthrown i get undefined and xmlhttprequest i get [object xmlhttprequest]

Comment: try `console.error(errorThrown);` if you're on Firefox or Safari.

Comment: @afekenholm write that as an answer, found out the error by this thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing in Firefox or Safari you may use the `console.error` function to debug any error thrown in your code.